# Agora Error: A value of type 'void Function(LocalInvitation)' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'void Function(LocalInvitation, String)'

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, agora.io, pubspec, agora-implementation

After adding Agora to the project it shows this error when I try to run the project.

```
/C:/Users/syedi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_uikit-1.3.3/lib/controllers/rtm_client_event_handler.dart:76:7: Error: A value of type 'void Function(LocalInvitation)' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'void Function(LocalInvitation, String)'.
- 'LocalInvitation' is from 'package:agora_rtm/src/utils.dart' ('/C:/Users/syedi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_rtm-1.5.7/lib/src/utils.dart').
 (AgoraRtmLocalInvitation invitation) {

/C:/Users/syedi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_uikit-1.3.3/lib/controllers/rtm_client_event_handler.dart:81:7: Error: A value of type 'void Function(LocalInvitation)' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'void Function(LocalInvitation, String)?'.
- 'LocalInvitation' is from 'package:agora_rtm/src/utils.dart' ('/C:/Users/syedi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/agora_rtm-1.5.7/lib/src/utils.dart').
(AgoraRtmLocalInvitation invitation) {
```

My dependencies version

```
agora_rtc_engine: ^6.1.0
agora_uikit: ^1.3.3
http: ^0.13.6
```

My Flutter version `3.7.1`